# How to make posts under custom post type not generate a URL / post

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I have a custom post type called `integrations`, which is being used to host basic information for integrations.

Here's how I've registered the post type:

```
register_post_type(
  'Integrations',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'integrations', 'Integration', 'Integrations',
    array(
      'menu_position' => 21,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'public' => false,
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
      'taxonomies' => array('categories'),
    )
  )
);
```

Now, I also have a page called "Integrations" which sits on `/integrations`. In order to make the archive page use the page template instead, I've used `template_include`:

```
function custom_integrations_template( $template ) {
  if ( is_page( 'integrations' )  ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'integration-page-template.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
      return $new_template ;
    }
  }
  return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_integrations_template', 999 );
```

`integration-page-template.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now, here's where my issues begin.

Under the "Integrations" custom post type, I have a post called "TaxCalc", which sits on `/integrations/taxcalc/`.

However, I also need to create a page, which will be a child of the "Integrations" page which sits on `/integrations/taxcalc/`.

Currently, when I access `/integrations/taxcalc/`, it takes me to a blank page, which is the post version.

Ideally, I do not want the posts under the "Integrations" post type to generate any URLs. To do this, I have tried `'publicly_queryable' => false`, however, it does not do anything.

How can I prevent a post type from generating URLs and would this cause any knock on effects? For example, prevent me from creating pages under the same slug?

### Edit (response to @Lewis)

Thanks for the answer. I have added `'rewrite' => false`, but the issue still remains.

Below is an integration **post** and you can see the permalink in the screenshot too:

[image]

When I go to that permalink `/integrations/card-taxcalc/`, it takes me to a page with just the header and footer. Ideally, this post shouldn't exist.

Now, below is a screenshot of my TaxCalc page setup:

[image]

As you can see, this page sits on `/integrations/taxcalc/`. However, when I go to this URL, it redirects me to `/integrations/card-taxcalc/`

### Edit 2

`theme_build_post_args`:

```
class theme_PTTaxArgBuilder{

  /**
   * Options will be merged into these, as opposed to using
   * the standard WordPress defaults.
   * @var array
   */
  public $postDefaults = array(
      'public'                => true,
      'publicly_queryable'    => true,
      'show_ui'               => true,
      'show_in_menu'          => true,
      'query_var'             => true,
      'rewrite'                => array( 'slug' => '' ),
      'capability_type'       => 'post',
      'has_archive'           => true,
      'hierarchical'          => false,
      'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
  );

  /**
   * Options will be merged into these, as opposed to using
   * the standard WordPress defaults.
   * @var array
   */
  public $taxonomyDefaults = array(
      'hierarchical'          => true,
      'show_ui'               => true,
      'show_admin_column'     => true,
      'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
      'query_var'             => true,
      'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => '' ),
  );

  /**
   * Build the post types labels based solely on the capitalised
   * singular and plural form.
   * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Post'
   * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Posts'
   */
  public function buildPostLabels( $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts' )
  {
      if($singular != 'Post' && $plural == 'Posts' ) {
          $plural = $singular . 's';
      }


      $labels = array(
          'name'               => _x($plural, 'post type general name', 'lightbox'),
          'singular_name'      => _x($singular, 'post type singular name', 'lightbox'),
          'menu_name'          => _x($plural, 'admin menu', 'lightbox'),
          'name_admin_bar'     => _x($singular, 'add new on admin bar', 'lightbox'),
          'add_new'            => _x('Add New', $singular, 'lightbox'),
          'add_new_item'       => __('Add New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
          'new_item'           => __('New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
          'edit_item'          => __('Edit ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
          'view_item'          => __('View ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
          'all_items'          => __('All ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
          'search_items'       => __('Search ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
          'parent_item_colon'  => __('Parent ' . $plural . ':', 'lightbox'),
          'not_found'          => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found.', 'lightbox'),
          'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found in Trash.', 'lightbox'),
      );


      return $labels;
  }

  /**
   * Generate the complete arguments ready for post type creation,
   * including the URL slug and merging of new defaults above.
   * @param string $slug     The URL slug for the post type, eg 'posts'
   * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Post'
   * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Posts'
   * @param array  $args     Additional arguments to override the defaults
   */
  public function buildPostArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
  {
      $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->postDefaults);

      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

      $args['labels'] = $this->buildPostLabels($singular, $plural);

      return $args;
  }

  /**
   * Build the taxonomies labels based solely on the capitalised
   * singular and plural form.
   * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Category'
   * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Categories'
   */
  public function buildTaxonomyLabels( $singular = 'Category', $plural = 'Categories' )
  {
      if($singular != 'Category' && $plural == 'Categories' ) {
          $plural = $singular . 's';
      }

      $labels = array(
          'name'                       => _x($plural, 'taxonomy general name'),
          'singular_name'              => _x($singular, 'taxonomy singular name'),
          'search_items'               => __('Search ' . $plural),
          'all_items'                  => __('All ' . $plural),
          'parent_item'                => __('Parent ' . $singular),
          'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent ' . $singular . ':'),
          'edit_item'                  => __('Edit ' . $singular),
          'update_item'                => __('Update ' . $singular),
          'add_new_item'               => __('Add New ' . $singular),
          'new_item_name'              => __('New ' . $singular . ' Name'),
          'menu_name'                  => __($plural),
          // Tags
          'popular_items'              => __('Popular ' . $plural),
          'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate ' . strtolower($plural) . ' with commas'),
          'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove ' . strtolower($plural)),
          'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used ' . strtolower($plural)),
          'not_found'                  => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found.'),
      );

      return $labels;
  }

  /**
   * Generate the complete arguments ready for taxonomy creation,
   * including the URL slug and merging of new defaults above.
   * @param string $slug     The URL slug for the taxonomy, eg 'category'
   * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Category'
   * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Categories'
   * @param array  $args     Additional arguments to override the defaults
   */
  public function buildTaxonomyArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Category', $plural = 'Categories', $args = array() )
  {
      $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->taxonomyDefaults);

      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

      $args['labels'] = $this->buildTaxonomyLabels($singular, $plural);

      return $args;
  }
}

/**
* These public functions exist as procedural functions to keep in style
* with WordPress theme development.
*/
function theme_build_post_args( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
{
  $builder = new theme_PTTaxArgBuilder;
  return $builder->buildPostArgs($slug, $singular, $plural, $args);
}
```

Comment: looks like you asked this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125278/how-to-disable-page-create-for-custom-post-type-but-allow-a-page-with-the-post and accepted an answer already, did that answer not work for you?

Comment: @TomJNowell The solution did work. However, at that time, my pages were under another level, for example, TaxCalc was on `/product/integrations/taxcalc`. However, now I've removed `/product` as a level so all integration pages sit under `/integrations`, and since then, these issues have arrived.

Comment: Also what is the `theme_build_post_args` function and where does it come from? Note that setting `rewrite` to `false` just means you want ugly permalinks in the form `index.php?post_type=....etc`

Comment: @TomJNowell - `theme_build_post_args` is helper function used to generate post type and taxonomy labels, as opposed to manually entering the various different options. I can post the function in the question if you like?

Comment: if you could, it might not be the issue but it'd be good to confirm and avoid people asking

Comment: @TomJNowell - No worries, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the class and function you're using, this method is a little problematic:

```php
  public function buildPostArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
  {
      $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->postDefaults);

      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

      $args['labels'] = $this->buildPostLabels($singular, $plural);

      return $args;
  }
```

If we ignore your problem, `$args['rewrite']['slug']` is going to generate a PHP warning if you set `rewrite` to false for trying to use it as an array.

So if we separate out the call into a variable like this:

```php
$args = theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'integrations', 'Integration', 'Integrations',
    [
        'menu_position' => 21,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
        'taxonomies' => array('categories'),
    ]
);
register_post_type(
    'Integrations',
    $args
);
```

We can now overwrite what your helper did, e.g.

```php
$args = theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'integrations', 'Integration', 'Integrations',
    [
        'menu_position' => 21,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
        'taxonomies' => array('categories'),
    ]
);

$args['public'] = false;
... etc ...

register_post_type(
    'Integrations',
    $args
);
```

In particular look at what it defines in `$postDefaults` and override those specifically to match what you want.

You might also want to ditch the function and just use the label setup parts to simplify things:

```php
$builder = new theme_PTTaxArgBuilder;
$args = [
    'labels' => $builder->buildPostLabels( 'Integration', 'Integrations' ),
    'menu_position' => 21,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
    'taxonomies' => array('categories'),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
];

register_post_type(
    'Integrations',
    $args
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But many thanks for highlighting the issues with the function, I probably would never had through the issue would have stemmed from there. Can confirm ditching the function altogether worked. Will look to correct aspects of the function based on your above in due time. Thanks again.